# Duplicate form value by transforming date format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: jquery

I have a form with an input that receives a date in YYYY-MM-DD format.
I need another input to receive this same information, in the Blur event, but in DD-MM-YYYY format, from a date picker.
With jQuery, I can get the value from the first input by ID and insert it into the second input, but I couldn't transform the date.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  jQuery("[id='date1']").on('blur', () => {
    jQuery("[id='date2']").val(
      jQuery("[id='date1']").val())
  })
});
</script>
```

I'm developing a project within wordpress, using JetEngine forms.
Can someone give me a light, please?!

Comment: Why can't you transform it?

Comment: You can use `split()` to split the input string into an array. Then create a new string by concatenating them in the desired order.

Comment: It would be beneficial for all if you could put up a working sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the input into an array using `-` as the delimiter. Reverse this and join it back to create the output.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  jQuery("#date1").on('blur', function() {
    let date_array = this.value.split('-');
    jQuery("#date2").val(date_array.reverse().join('-'))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type date here: <input id="date1">
<br>
Output date: <input id="date2">
```